# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'

Tags: c#

```
if (Console.CursorTop=3 && Console.CursorLeft==7) {
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

there is an error

```
Error   1   Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: asked - answered (in about 15 seconds)

Comment: One equal sign is an assignment operator, two is an equality operator.

Comment: C# you did it again with your ==, I know it makes sense but my brain wants to write just the one. Always causes me trouble =)

Answer (score 12):

Don't you mean (notice the double equal signs)

```
Console.CursorTop == 3
```

other wise its an assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Correct your syntax, replace =3 with ==3

```
if (Console.CursorTop==3 && Console.CursorLeft==7)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to compare CursorTop to 3 then you need `if (Console.CursorTop==3 && Console.CursorLeft==7)`

Answer (score 1):

In C# = is not used for comparison of two values. In order to make a comparison between two values you need to put == in your statement.

```
if (Console.CursorTop**==**3 && Console.CursorLeft==7) {
     Console.WriteLine();
}
```